# NSIS: How to check if a var exists

Tags: nsis

What is the best way to check if a var exists in NSIS?

Currently I do something like this:

```
${If} $NonExistentVar == $$NonExistentVar
```

But this won't work as expected in case an existing var `some_var` have the value of `$some_var`, I know it's rare but, is there a better way of checking it?

```
section non_existent_var
    detailprint "non existent: $NonExistentVar"
    var /global ExistentVar
    detailprint "existent: $ExistentVar"
    ${If} $NonExistentVar == $$NonExistentVar
        detailprint "PASS: NonExistent doesn't exist"
    ${Else}
        detailprint "FAIL: NonExistent exists"
    ${EndIf}

    ${If} $ExistentVar == $$ExistentVar
        detailprint "FAIL: ExistentVar doesn't exist"
    ${Else}
        detailprint "PASS: ExistentVar exists"
    ${EndIf}

    strcpy $ExistentVar "$$ExistentVar"

    ${If} $ExistentVar == $$ExistentVar
        detailprint "FAIL: ExistentVar doesn't exist"
    ${Else}
        detailprint "PASS: ExistentVar exists"
    ${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

gives:

```
non existent: $NonExistentVar
existent: 
PASS: NonExistent doesn't exist
PASS: ExistentVar exists
FAIL: ExistentVar doesn't exist
Completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a define? This is a check that should happen at compile time after all.

```
!macro DeclareDetactableVariable name
!ifndef VAR_${name}
Var /Global ${name}
!define VAR_${name}
!endif
!macroend

!insertmacro DeclareDetactableVariable foo
!ifdef VAR_foo
...
!endif
```